# Ruby/rails sort_by not ordering properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a long array of `Photo` model objects, and I want to sort them by `created_at`, newest first, then get a new array with the first 21 photos.

My problem is that the final array is not ordered properly.

Here is my code:

```
@recent_photos = photos.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.first(21)
```

when I print out `@recent_photos` the `created_at` values are ordered like this:

```
1458948707
1458943713
1458947042
1458945171
...
```

What is the correct way to sort objects?

UPDATE:

here's how the initial list is compiled:

```
photos = @user.photos
@following = @user.following
@following.each do |f|
  photos += f.photos if f.id != @user.id
end
@user.memberships.each do |group|
  photos += group.photos
end
```

SOLUTION:

problem was with the question - I wanted to sort by `timestamp` not `created_at`, and those were `timestamp` values in the output

Comment: The sorting should work fine from what I can see, what class type is your ``created_at``?

Comment: idk, it was auto generated by Rails, but if its a string that might be the problem?

Comment: Could you run ``photos.map(&:created_at).first(21)`` and paste it? Your sorting should definitely be in the correct order unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ran that and they are definitely in order in that output

Comment: You'll need to add a bit more information, what does 'photos' look like? is it an array of active record objects? or hashes? A small mock model should help. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You can crunch it all down into a single query:

```
@recent_photos = Photo.where(
  user_id: @user.following_ids
).order('created_at DESC').limit(21)
```

You really do not want to be doing N queries for each of these as it will get slower and slower as a person has more people they're following. If they follow 10,000 people that's a ridiculous number of queries.

If you add a `:through` definition to your model you may even be able to query the photos directly:

```
 has_many :follower_photos,
   class_name: 'Photo',
   through: :followers
```

Whatever your constraints are, boil them down to something you can query in one shot whenever possible. If that's not practical, get it down to a predictable number of queries, never N.

Comment: but how would I get all followers photos, groups photos, and personal photos with the same query? the example is just for followers

Comment: Ideally you have a singular table that represents a person or a group, or you create stub "person" records for groups to work around this. You can also use Single Table Inheritance (STI) to combine person and group into the same table, or use a polymorphic table to join them but that can be considerably more messy. Ideally the STI approach is the easiest to effect. If you do have two different relations, you can join them with the `.or(...)` method to add another condition set.

Comment: For performance reasons I tend to avoid `or` situations whenever possible. MySQL has to do a lot of work to combine two result sets and sort them if you use that. Using a single table is super efficient if you can have an index on the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` criteria.

Comment: yea I'm not sure that I can avoid an `or`, b/c it shouldn't return the person's photos from a group that they've left, and there are other nuances.. but anyway, speed of implementation is more important that the speed of the function rn, so could you help me find a way to sort the array I already have?

Comment: `sort_by` should do it. If you're getting random results you must be altering the array at some point.

Comment: yea that's the OP, why doesn't this work? `@recent_photos = photos.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.first(21)` there are no other manipulations afterwards

Comment: It should. Are you sure `photos` is a flat array of objects and not something else?

Comment: Ohh. I'll take the advice eventually on rewriting this, but my problem was that I wanted to sort by `timestamp` not by `created_at`.. they are different values in this app, so it makes sense that they would be ordered differently

Comment: Ah, that would do it. Always give a little attention to performance considerations. You don't want to paint yourself into a corner because of a bad schema design.

Comment: Thats a good point, rethinking the schema is probably not something to put off until there's 10k users

Comment: I tried using this exact code in a new function, but it returned an empty array. Do you know what could be wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344662/ruby-on-rails-optimal-search-with-array-of-filter-values

Comment: @Cbas As always look in `log/development.log` to see what query shows up, and from there verify that the values are correct by looking in your database.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@recent_photos = Photo.order('created_at desc').first(21)
```

Comment: I can't query `Photo` directly, b/c the initial photo list is a select group of objects, not query-able with SQL

Comment: ah--I see that now...could you show how you're building that array of objects?